# KafkaCache io.kcache.exceptions.CacheInitializationException: Failed trying to create or validate topic my-topic

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka

I have an application running [KCache](https://github.com/rayokota/kcache). The application consists of several threads that each polls from a topic and then saves the records to their own kcache. Periodically, each thread reads a set of the stored record and analyze them. The application is deployed on OpenShift as a container and runs fine for a good period of time.

However, after about twelve hours of runtime, the application crashes with the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.kcache.exceptions.CacheInitializationException: Failed trying to create or validate my-topic-kcache
    at io.kcache.KafkaCache.createOrVerifyTopic(KafkaCache.java:350)
    at io.kcache.KafkaCache.init(KafkaCache.java:267)
    at utils.Cache.<init>(Cache.kt:40)
    at consumers.MyThread.<init>(MyThread.kt:39)
    at ApplicationKt.module(Application.kt:88)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Static.call(CallerImpl.kt:106)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:108)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod$kotlin_reflection(KCallableImpl.kt:159)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:112)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.callFunctionWithInjection(CallableUtils.kt:119)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.executeModuleFunction(CallableUtils.kt:36)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:332)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartupFor(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:356)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.access$launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:30)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:312)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:310)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartup(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:338)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:310)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:143)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:277)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:174)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(EngineMain.kt:26)
    at ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:33)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1632808693387, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=-9223372036854775709) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:272)
    at io.kcache.KafkaCache.createOrVerifyTopic(KafkaCache.java:336)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1632808693387, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=-9223372036854775709) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: listTopics
{"@timestamp":"2021-09-28T07:57:57.759+02:00","@version":"1","message":"Thread kafka-cache-reader-thread-thread1-kcache exiting with uncaught exception: ","logger_name":"io.kcache.utils.ShutdownableThread","thread_name":"kafka-cache-reader-thread-thread1-kcache","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space\n"}
Exception in thread "thread1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "kafka-cache-reader-thread-thread1-kcache" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

The caches have the following configuration:

```
val cacheProps = Properties()
            cacheProps[KafkaCacheConfig.KAFKACACHE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] =
                appConfig.propertyOrNull("kafka.bootstrapServers")?.getString()
            cacheProps[KafkaCacheConfig.KAFKACACHE_GROUP_ID_CONFIG] =
                appConfig.propertyOrNull("kafka.consumerGroupIdPrefix")?.getString() + "-$name-kcache"
            cacheProps[KafkaCacheConfig.KAFKACACHE_TOPIC_CONFIG] =
                appConfig.propertyOrNull("applicationId")?.getString() + "$name-kcache"
            cacheProps[KafkaCacheConfig.KAFKACACHE_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG] =
                appConfig.propertyOrNull("kafka.securityProtocol")?.getString()
```

Has anyone experienced anything similar, or have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Increase the heap space of your application

Comment: So there is a limited storage space on the `KCache` topic? I thought one of the properties of Kafka is the ability to store large amounts of data? For my application, the topic will at maximum contain 60 000 avro records before I manually delete the oldest records. Should not the cache be able to handle this amount of records?

Comment: Has nothing to do with the topic on the Kafka broker. Your JVM memory is getting an OOM

Comment: Taking a heap memory dump of my application, I can see that `KCache` implements an `InMemoryCache` local cache where all the records are stored after polling.

Unfortunately, this makes me a little confused on how kafka and its topics are used with `KCache`? I thought that the topic worked as a cache itself and my application extracted records from that topic? Instead, it looks like all the records are stored locally? However, the KCache stores the data persistently , as my application have access to all the records after restart. How is that possible if it is only stored in the local cache?

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if you could give a brief overview on how `KCache` works and how the different components interact :)

Comment: I don't know how it works or how it even differs from just a KTable with RocksDB. I suggest you open a Github issue for the project if you really need documentation of how it works